# Game of Life with file read for world generation - string index out of range issue

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

Like the title says, I've being working on a variant of Conway's Game of Life in python that can read a "world" from a file and generate the starting world from that. However, in my code, I'm being given a "string index out of range" issue at the line while(aLine[currentCharacter] != NEWLINE), and I can't figure out why.

If it helps, in the input files " " is treated as a dead cell, and "*" is treated as a living cell.

Thank you for the help and please let me know if there's any additional info I should provide

```
def fileReadWorld():
    fileOK = False
    world = [] 
    row = 0
    column = 0
    while (fileOK == False):
        try:
            filename = input("Name of input file: ")        
            inputfile = open(filename,"r") 
            fileOK = True
            aLine = inputfile.readline()
            if(aLine == ""):
                print("The file %s" %(filename), "is empty.")
                fileOK = False
            else:
                aLine = inputfile.readline()
                row = 0
                while(aLine != ""):
                    currentCharacter = 0
                    world.append([])
                    while(aLine[currentCharacter] != "\n"):
                        world[row].append(aLine[currentCharacter])
                        currentCharacter = currentCharacter + 1
                    row = row + 1  
                    aLine = inputfile.readline()                                                 
                inputfile.close()
                maxRows = row
                maxColumns = len(world[0]) 
                return(world, maxRows, maxColumns)
        except IOError:
            print("Problem reading from file %s" %(filename))
            fileOK = False
```

The input file I am using is

```
    *     
     *    
   ***
```

(it should display as a 10x10 grid)

Comment: If the file is not empty, you throw away the first line without using it.

Comment: In Python, `if`, `while`, and `return` statements do not get extra parens.  That's just C and C++.

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem.  Perhaps you should post the input file you are using.

Comment: @TimRoberts Alright, the input file I am using is above now although it does cut out the spaces here

Comment: as for throwing away the first line, how does that work?

Comment: You have `aLine = inputfile.readline()`.  If that is not empty, then you do `aLine = inputfile.readline()` again, which throws away the first line you read.

Comment: You MIGHT consider using '.' instead of ' ', just because it's so hard to see if you really have spaces in there.

Comment: Try using a debugger.  Why should anyone debug your code for you?  You might actually learn something.

Comment: @TomServo  Why?  Because that's exactly what StackOverflow is for.  Why are you here?

Comment: @TimRoberts I consider any poster who hasn't run code through a debugger to have amply demonstrated a lack of research effort.  It is reasonable to do that first; a quick debugger session can impart more understanding than an "answer pellet" from someone here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simpler solution with the same result:

```
def main():
    world = [] 
    while True:
        try:
            filename = input("Name of input file: ")        
            for aLine in open(filename,"r") 
                world.append(list(aLine[:-1]))
            if world:
                maxRows = len(world)
                maxColumns = len(world[0]) 
                return world, maxRows, maxColumns
            print("The file %s" %(filename), "is empty.")
        except IOError:
            print("Problem reading from file %s" %filename)

print(main())
```

Comment: sorry for the late response - this was able to get this part of the program working for me, thank you so much